# Sequelize JS: Include with one to many relation ship

Tags: javascript, one-to-many, sequelize.js

hi i got a problem i'd like to express below:
lets say i have 2 models defined:  GameMap and Player,

```
GameMap.hasMany(Player, { foreignKey: 'map_id' });
```

then i would like to perform a query where each Player contains a GameMap object in its query,

```
Player.findAll(){
   include: {
    // how to map Player.map_id onto a GameMap object?
  }
}
```

i can do it the other way so that GameMap query contains its Players, but id want the opposite of it, couldnt solve this problem using documentation,
thx

Answer (score 1):

```
GameMap.hasMany(Player, { foreignKey: 'map_id'});
Player.belongsTo(GameMap, { foreignKey: 'map_id'});
```

Both models need to be associated with themselves through the same foreign_key.
Now inside Player query I can access its GameMap object.